# what is the role of directives in angular 2.0 as compared to angular 1.x?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular2-template, angular2-directives

What is the role of directives in Angular 2.0 and how would you compare and contrast this with the role of directives in Angular 1.x?  I'm not quite clear if directives are now only used internally, if they've been replaced by components, if they're still supported but in a different manifestation or if they're still supported but not recommended.  I also watched a video where the presenter mentioned that the Angular team eliminated over 40 directives in Angular 2.  I only did a small amount of work in Angular 1.x and I'm just ramping up with Angular 2.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html